# Drawing moving objects in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw

I am trying to make a game with an Archer and moving balloon.

In a GameControler I have 2 lists with balloons and arrows and those I have to paint on screen. I have a class GUI which paint a `JPanel Menu` when the game is not running and the graphics game when the game is running. In class GameControler I'm counting time and established frames/sec.

I don`t know how to paint those 2 list on screen ( with moving objects ).
I tried to extend`JPanel`or implements`Canvas` but nothing helpful, because I need in GUI to do a function that when is called will draw all objects.

```
class GameControler
..........
@Override
public void run() {
    double lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true)
    {
        if(frameTime(lastTime) == false)
            continue;
        Gui.update();
        if(Gui.getInGameGui() == true)
        {               
            keyboardListener = new KeyboardListener();
            gameState = new GameState(Level, ArrowList, BalloonList);
            while(gameState.isLevelRunning() == true)
            {
                if(frameTime(lastTime) == false)
                    continue;
                gameState.update();
                deseneazaObiecteJoc();
            }
            Gui.setInGameGui(false);
            Gui.update();
            FinalScore = gameState.getSocre();
        }            
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
 }

private boolean frameTime(double lastTime) {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime < 20)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }  
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't draw moving objects in a JPanel.  You erase the JPanel and draw objects in a JPanel performing the paintComponent method.  You achieve the illusion of motion by erasing and drawing on the JPanel performing the repaint method many times per second.  Take a look at my [Retro Snake Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=768) article to see how to code an animation.

Comment: Oh, and don't try a Thread sleep for less than 5 milliseconds.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).